# Python. Attach data to asyncio.Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Is there proper way to attach additional data to `asyncio.create_task()`?  The example is

```py
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
   name: str
   url_to_download: str
   size: int
   ...

async def download_file(url: str):
   return await download_impl()

objs: list[Foo] = [obj1, obj2, ...]

# Question
# How to attach the Foo object to the each task?
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(download_file(obj.url_to_download)) for obj in objs]

for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
   # Question
   # How to find out which Foo obj corresponds the downloaded data?
   data = await task
   process(data)
```

There is also way to forward the `Foo` object to the `download_file` and return it with the downloaded data, but it is poor design. Do I miss something, or anyone has a better design to solve that problem?

Comment: Are you thinking of passing to `download_file` a `Foo` (instead of `url_to_download`), then returning a tuple `(foo, await download_impl())`?  Is that what you are calling a "poor design"?  That would seem to solve your problem efficiently with only a couple of lines of additional code.  Why do you think it's a poor design?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just want a way to match the returned values from all your tasks to the instances of `Foo` whose `url_to_download` attributes you passed as arguments to said tasks.

Since all you are doing in that last loop is blocking until all tasks are completed, you may as well simply run the coroutines concurrently via [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). The order of the individual return values in the list it returns corresponds to the order of the coroutines passed to it as arguments:

```py
from asyncio import gather, run
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    url_to_download: str
    ...


async def download_file(url: str):
    return url


async def main() -> None:
    objs: list[Foo] = [Foo("foo"), Foo("bar"), Foo("baz")]
    returned_values = await gather(
        *(download_file(obj.url_to_download) for obj in objs)
    )
    print(returned_values)  # ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

That means you can simply match the `objs` and `returned_values` via index or [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them or whatever you need to do.

---

As for your comment that saving the returned the returned value in an attribute of the object itself is "poor design", I see absolutely no justification for that assessment. That would also be a perfectly valid way and arguably even cleaner. You might even define a `download` method on `Foo`  for that purpose. But that is another discussion.

Comment: _Since all you are doing in that last loop is blocking until all tasks are completed_ but I also run `process` function, it needs to be run as soon as file is downloaded.

Comment: @yvhnta Then combine it into one coroutine with `download_file` and run those concurrently.